# find point of intersection between two arc

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math

I'm creating a game for kids. It's creating a triangle using 3 lines. How I approached this is I create two arcs(semi circle) from two end points of a base line. But I couldn't figure how to find the point of intersection of those two arc. I've search about it but only found point of intersection between two straight lines. Is there any method to find this point of intersection? Below is the figure of two arcs drawn from each end of the baseline.

[image]

Comment: You have not specified problem properly. Try to describe it more formally or make a sketch

Comment: I've uploaded the sketch

Comment: This sounds more like a math problem to me. Have you tried asking on other math-related StackExchange sites ?

Comment: So you have coordinates of the base segment ends and lengths of two edges? (Note I ignore base length)

Comment: Yes, I have the length of 3 sides.

Comment: Are those arcs actually circles arcs or are they some arbitrary smooth curves? If they are circles arcs, are radii the same for the two circles?

Comment: they are circles and their center points are the each end of the baseline. The radius are different.

Comment: @TheGunners you've got some good Answers there. I'm learning so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume centers of the circle are (`x1`, `y1`) and (`x2`, `y2`), radii are `R1` and `R2`. Let the ends of the base be `A` and `B` and the target point be `T`. We know that `AT` = `R1` and `BT` = `R2`. IMHO the simplest trick to find `T` is to notice that difference of the *squares* of the distances is a known constant `(R1^2 - R2^2)`. And it is easy to see that the line the contains points meeting this condition is actually a straight line perpendicular to the base. Circles equations:

```
(x - x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 = R1^2    
(x - x2)^2 + (y-y2)^2 = R2^2
```

If we subtract one from another we'll get:

```
(x2 - x1)(2*x - x1 - x2) + (y2 - y1)(2*y - y1 - y2) = R1^2 - R2^2
```

Let's `x0 = (x1 + x2)/2` and `y0 = (y1 + y2)/2` - the coordinates of the center. Let also the length of the base be `L` and its projections `dx = x2 - x1` and `dy = y2 - y1` (i.e. `L^2 = dx^2 + dy^2`). And let's `Q = R1^2 - R2^2` So we can see that

```
2 * (dx * (x-x0) + dy*(y-y0)) = Q
```

So the line for all `(x,y)` pairs with `R1^2 - R2^2` = `Q` = const is a straight line orthogonal to the base (because coefficients are exactly `dx` and `dy`).

Let's find the point `C` on the base that is the intersection with that line. It is easy - it splits the base so that difference of the squares of the lengths is `Q`. It is easy to find out that it is the point on a distance `L/2 + Q/(2*L)` from `A` and `L/2 - Q/(2*L)` from `B`. So now we can find that

```
  TC^2 = R1^2 - (L/2 + Q/(2*L))^2
```

Substituting back `Q` and simplifying a bit we can find that

```
  TC^2 = (2*L^2*R1^2 + 2*L^2*R2^2 + 2*R1^2*R2^2 - L^4 - R1^4 - R2^4) / (4*L^2)
```

So let's

```
 a = (R1^2 - R2^2)/(2*L)
 b = sqrt(2*L^2*R1^2 + 2*L^2*R2^2 + 2*R1^2*R2^2 - L^4 - R1^4 - R2^4) / (2*L)
```

Note that formula for `b` can also be written in a different form:

```
 b = sqrt[(R1+R2+L)*(-R1+R2+L)*(R1-R2+L)*(R1+R2-L)] / (2*L)
```

which looks quite similar to the [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula). And this is not a surprise because `b` is effectively the length of the height to the base `AB` from `T` in the triangle `ABT` so its length is `2*S/L` where `S` is the area of the triangle. And the triangle `ABT` obviously has sides of lengths `L`, `R1` and `R2` respectively.

To find the target `T` we need to move `a` along the base and `b` in a perpendicular direction. So coordinates of `T` calculated from the middle of the segment are:

```
 Xt = x0 + a * dx/L ± b * dy / L
 Yt = y0 + a * dy/L ± b * dx / L
```

Here `±` means that there are two solutions: one on either side of the base line.

Partial case: if `R1 = R2 = R`, then `a = 0` and `b = sqrt(R^2 - (L/2)^2)` which makes obvious sense: `T` lies on the segment bisector on a length of `sqrt(R^2 - (L/2)^2)` from the middle of the segment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your answer but it didn't work. I tried with the following:  `x1 = 100, y1 = 500, x2 = 400, y2 = 500, R1 = 240, R2 = 180 and L = 300`. And also when I substract `(x - x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 = R1^2 and (x - x2)^2 + (y-y2)^2 = R2^2` I got different answer. I got `(x1 - x2)(x1 + x2 - 2x) + (y1 - y2)(y1 + y2 - 2y) = R1^2 - R2^2`

Comment: @TheGunners, could you provide some test data you tried so I can check?

Comment: `x1 = 100, y1 = 500, x2 = 400, y2 = 500, R1 = 240, R2 = 180 and L = 300`. I also got different outcome when substracting `(x - x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 = R1^2` and `(x - x2)^2 + (y-y2)^2 = R2^2`

Comment: @TheGunners, sorry, I made a mistake at the very end in formulas for `Xt` and `Yt` I messed up directions. `dx` and `dy` should have been switched in those two lines (now I fixed it in the answer). With your data I get `a` = `42`, `b` = `144`, `x0` = `250`, `y0` = `400` so `Xt` = `292` and `Yt` = `644`. To check: `240^2` = `57600` = `36864 + 20736` = `(292 - 100)^2 + (644 - 500)^2` and `180^2` = `32400` = `11664 + 20736` = `(292 - 400)^2 + (644 - 500)^2` P.S. and yes I messed up with `dx` and `dy` which should've been `dx = x2 - x1` and `dy = y2 - y1`. Let me know if this still doesn't work.

Comment: thank you for the answer. It worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

While you have not stated clearly, I assume that you have points with coordinates `(A.X, A.Y)` and `(B.X, B.Y)` and lengths of two sides `LenA` and `LenB` and need to find coordinates of point C.

So you can make equation system  exploiting circle equation:

```
(C.X - A.X)^2 + (C.Y - A.Y)^2 = LenA^2
(C.X - B.X)^2 + (C.Y - B.Y)^2 = LenB^2
```

and solve it for unknowns C.X, C.Y.

Not that it is worth to subtract A coordinates from all others, make and solve simpler system (the first equation becomes `C'.X^2 + C'.Y^2 = LenA^2`), then add A coordinates again

Answer (score 1):

So I actually needed this to design a hopper to lift grapes during the wine harvest. Tried to work it out myself but the algebra is horrible, so I had a look on the web -in the end I did it myself but introduced some intermediate variables (that I calculate in Excel - this should also work for the OP since the goal was a calculated solution). In fairness this is really much the same as previous solutions but hopefully a little clearer.

Problem:
What are the coordinates of a point P(Xp,Yp) distance Lq from point Q(Xq,Yq) and distance Lr from point R(Xr,Yr)?

Let us first map the problem onto to new coordinate system where Lq is the origin, thus Q’ = (0,0), let (x,y) = P’(Xp-Xq,Yp-Yq) and let (a,b) = R’(Xr-Xq,Yr-Yq).

We may now write:

x^2 + y^2 = Lq^2            -(1)

(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = Lr^2    -(2)

Expanding 2:

x^2 – 2ax + a^2 + y^2 -2ay + b^2 =Lr^2

Subtracting 1 and rearranging

2by  = -2ax + a2 + b2 - Lr^2+ Lq^2

For convenience, let c = a^2 + b^2 + Lq^2 + Lr^2  (these are all known constants so c may be easily computed), thus we obtain:

y = -ax/b + c/2b

Substituting into 1 we obtain:

x^2 + (-a/b x + c/2b)^2 = Lq^2

Multiply the entire equation by b^2 and gather terms:

(a^2  + b^2) x2 -ac x + c/4 + Lq^2 b^2    = 0

Let A = (a2  + b2), B= -ac  ,and C= c/4 + Lq^2 b^2

Use the general solution for a quadratic

x = (-B +-SQRT(B^2-4AC))/2A

Substitute back into 1 to get:

y= SQRT(Lq^2  - x^2 )
(This avoids computational difficulties where b = 0)

Map back to original coordinate system

P = (x+Xq, y + Yq)

Hope this helps, sorry about the formatting, I had this all pretty in Word, but lost it